# python corporate firewall proxy 407 authentication required error

Tags: python

I am behind a corporate firewall, while I can access the pypi website, I cannot install packages via pip. I get the 407 error:

"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired'))': /simple"

I tried various options like:

> pip install --proxy=http://proxyhost:proxy_port PackageName which doesn't work

and even setting

> http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port
>   https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port

none of these work because of the corporate firewall. How can I install the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of struggling the easiest solution is:

1. To visit the package website on pypi e.g.
   https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files
2. Find the relevant wheel,
   download it on your local machine
3. Open command prompt and navigate
   to the location where the package is downloaded e.g. "C:\"
4. Run pip
   install pyodbc-4.0.24-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
5. Voila the package should
   be installed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was able to resolve it by installing a local [cntlm proxy](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) on my machine (which can be done even *without* admin permissions by simply downloading the .zip folder. You'll need to adapt the `cntlm.ini` file (insert the Username, Domain, Password (you can omit the password and enter it at startup), Proxy and Listen variables (see [here](https://gist.github.com/sfabijanski/efcd7ca3e8c52edd5425) for some more detailed instructions) and create a `pip.ini`-file in a folder named "pip" in your user directory (that worked for me, you might be able to put it somewhere else, too) with the following content

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
proxy = # your local proxy address here (usually 127.0.0.1:3128)
```

After that, start the local proxy (I use a batch script) with `path/to/your/cntlm.exe -c cntlm.ini -I -f` and then pip should route your web requests to the local proxy which will then handle authentication at your corporate firewall for you.

With this setup, I am currently able to use any and all `pip install`-commands from behind the corporate firewall just fine

Comment: I wish this would work :( but after several hours with cntlm, I had to move to the manual solution